# SharePoint people picker communication with active directory, was it http or tcp?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, people-picker, https

SharePoint 2013 people picker communication with active directory, was it http protocol or tcp protocol?

Answer (score 2):

Hello [here is great article about ports](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2009/01/21/people-picker-portprotocol-requirements/):

Conceptually the port requirements become clear,

1. we know we are executing an LDAP query against a directory source
   impersonating an account with access to that source, binding to the
   users container and a SearchResultCollection object to hold a
   collection of SearchResults returned by the FindAll method (see
   example later in this article) and
2. We require name resolution to resolve a directory server at the
   destination.  Specifically when you enter a name or partial name in
   the user interface the Windows API will return a SID for that
   account, once the SID has been acquired, the People Picker attempts
   to retrieve additional information about that user from the Active
   Directory.  Quite clearly under these conditions we will require
   either port 389 LDAP or port 636 sLDAP, or where a Domain Controller
   is granted the Global Catalog role, 3268 and 3269, and in both cases
   53 DNS, 445 Directory Services in addition to authentication
   protocols, Kerberos, Kerberos-Adm, and Kerberos-IV.

A complete list of ports and protocols required to successfully instantiate and execute a People Picker request are as follows (WFE):

```
TCP/UDP 135, 137, 138, 139 (RPC) 
TCP/UDP 389 by default, customizable (LDAP) 
TCP 636 by default, customizable (LDAP SSL) 
TCP 3268 (LDAP GC) 
TCP 3269 (LDAP GC SSL) 
TCP/UDP 53 (DNS) 
TCP/UDP 88 (Kerberos) 
TCP/UDP 445 (Directory Services) 
TCP/UDP 749 (Kerberos-Adm) [Opt.] 
TCP port 750 (Kerberos-IV) [Opt.]
```

*Hope it helps!*

Answer (score 2):

For full-functionality, PeoplePicker requires the following ports to all DomainControllers on the same ActiveDirectory Site:

- TCP/UDP 135, 137, 138, 139 (RPC)
- TCP/UDP 389 by default, customizable (LDAP)
- TCP 636 by default, customizable (LDAP SSL)
- TCP 3268 (LDAP GC)
- TCP 3269 (LDAP GC SSL)
- TCP/UDP 53 (DNS)
- TCP/UDP 88 (Kerberos)
- TCP/UDP 445 (Directory Services)
- TCP/UDP 749 (Kerberos-Adm) [Opt.]
- TCP port 750 (Kerberos-IV) [Opt.]

No HTTP or HTTPS traffic included here!

Reference: [People Picker Port/Protocol Requirements](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2009/01/21/people-picker-portprotocol-requirements/)

Comment: you totally copied my answer from the same link, I reported you

Comment: I posted exactly 17 seconds after your answer. I think it is not possible to steal an answer in such a short time. The upvote for your answer comes also from me.